# How to compare two string arrays and store the matching values in another string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string, linq

```
string[] a = { 2; a; 3; b; 4; c}
string[] b = { 2; a; 6; c}
```

I want to compare this two arrays and remove the all digit(2,3,4,6)values and store match string values in another array.

I want the result like this:

```
string[] c = {a; c;}
```

I was tried this but it was adding all the values.

```
string[] result = a.Union(b).ToArray();
```

Comment: `Union` does NOT work like that. Use `Intersect`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Where`:

```
string[] result = a.Intersect(b).Where(c => !char.IsDigit(c[0])).ToArray();
```

Based on your comment to remove or replace the colon (;):

```
string[] result = a.Intersect(b).Where(c => !char.IsDigit(c[0]))
                                .Select(c => c.Replace(';',' ')).ToArray();
```

Comment: How to remove  or replace the colon (;) form string array.

Answer (score 0):

you need Intersect not Union

```
string[] result  = a.Intersect(b).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution would be to use `Linq` to do the job

```
int tmp;
var c = a.Where(x => b.Contains(x) && !int.TryParse(x, out tmp)).ToArray();
```

Comment: No. It couldn't fix it since it has a `;` at the end of the digits. So the `!int.TryParse(2;, out tmp)` will evaluate to false and it returns it as result too.

Comment: notation of this list is invalid C# structure. there should be `,` in place of `;` so i tougth it's typo error. no matter what would you like to achive, "123" is a number, "123;" is a string.